# Google maps api. Multiple markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps

```
var cityMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('cityMap'), {
   zoom: 12,
});
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var services = document.getElementsByClassName('s__item');
var marker;
var geocoderCity = new google.maps.Geocoder();

for ( i=0; i < services.length; i++ ) {
    var address = $(services[i]).find('.s__item__address_at').text();
    var contentString = address;

    geocoderCity.geocode({'address': address}, function (results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        center = results[0].geometry.location;
        cityMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: cityMap,
            position: center,                   
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker) {
            return function() {
               infowindow.setContent(contentString);
               infowindow.open(cityMap, marker);
            }
        })(marker));
    }
});
}
```

In `s__item__address_at` blocks there is an addresses. I get locations using geocoder. Then I try to add infowindows on the map, but I get only last result of iteration. How can I fix it?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/go85gyxk/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a clousure for make the var instance available to listener

```
  function markerListener(aMap, aMarker, aContent){
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker) {
              return function() {
                 infowindow.setContent(aContent);
                 infowindow.open(aMap, aMarker);
              }
          });
  }

  var cityMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('cityMap'), {
     zoom: 12,
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var services = document.getElementsByClassName('s__item');
  var marker;
  var geocoderCity = new google.maps.Geocoder();



  for ( i=0; i < services.length; i++ ) {
      var address = $(services[i]).find('.s__item__address_at').text();
      var contentString = address;

      geocoderCity.geocode({'address': address}, function (results, status) {
      if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          center = results[0].geometry.location;
          cityMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: cityMap,
              position: center,                   
          });

          markerListener(cityMap, marker, contentString)
      }
  });
```

}